# FPDF is not rendering correctly

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

i am creating a PDF in PHP using FPDF library, but i am unable to get my desired results i-e i am unable to write text to PDF every other thing is done correctly , i have used both methods

```
$pdf->SetXY();
$pdf->Write(0,"Some Text");
```

and

```
$pdf->Text(10,10, "Some other Text");
```

here is my full code

```
<?php
include_once "fpdf/fpdf.php";

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.5);
$pdf->Text(10, 10, "Test Data");
$pdf->Line(10, 15, 200, 15);
$pdf->Line(10, 280, 200, 280);

$pdf->Line(10, 15, 10, 280);
$pdf->Line(200, 15, 200, 280);

$pdf->Rect(10, 15, 190, 15);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(10, 'Text1');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Using above code i am getting following output.
[image]

What do you think i am doing wrong?

UPDATE :-- As Mr. Rajdeep Paul suggested i was missing following line of code.

```
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","10");
```

i added it in the code and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF is not displaying anything because you didn't set the font. Set font like this:

```
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","10");
```

Here's the reference:

- http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php

    include_once "fpdf/fpdf.php";

    $pdf=new FPDF();

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","10");

    $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.5);
    $pdf->Text(10, 10, "Test Data");
    $pdf->Line(10, 15, 200, 15);
    $pdf->Line(10, 280, 200, 280);

    $pdf->Line(10, 15, 10, 280);
    $pdf->Line(200, 15, 200, 280);

    $pdf->Rect(10, 15, 190, 15);
    $pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
    $pdf->Write(10, 'Text1');
    $pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: ah man you are genious. and i am an a** hole, just a little mistake and ARGHHH

Comment: @Tahir Glad I could help. Happy coding. ;-)